# F1 score computation when target labels contain only a subset of the allowed labels

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, multiclass-classification

I have a 3-class classification problem.
My predicted labels consist of all three classes.
However, my target labels have only 2 of the three classes present.
For example:

```
predicted = [1,1,2,3,2,1]
target = [1,1,2,2,2,1]
```

How should I go about computing the F1 score in this case?
I'm currently using `sklearn`'s `f1_score` function with `macro` average.
But this leads to a low F1 score value for cases like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f1_score` offers a parameter called `labels` that let's you define a set of labels to include in case that `average != 'binary'`.

For example, if you are only interested in the performance of your classifier for the classes `1` and `2`, you can do:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score


predicted = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
target = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]

print(f1_score(target, predicted, average='macro', labels=[1, 2]))
# 0.9
```